# I can't bind Meta-h to backward-kill-word using bash/readline for my xterms

Tags: linux, xterm, readline, xmodmap, inputrc

- redhat-release: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.4 (Maipo)
- bash version: 4.2.46(2)
- xterm version: X.Org 7.6.0(295)

I'm using `xmodmap` to map my Meta keys correctly. Confirmed this via `xev`. (Have also tried with them mapped as Alt keys, with no change in results.)

Some current variable bindings:

```
> bind -v | grep meta
set convert-meta off
set enable-meta-key on
set input-meta on
set meta-flag on
set output-meta on
```

Current bindings for `backward-kill-word`:

```
> bind -p | grep 'backward.kill.word'
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
"\e-h": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
"�": backward-kill-word
# shell-backward-kill-word (not bound)
```

I've tried both syntaxes for the binding I want in my `.inputrc` file:

```
"\M-h": backward-kill-word
Meta-h: backward-kill-word
```

But when I do `bind -f ~/.inputrc` I don't get the behavior I want; and I get the same reported bindings for `backward-kill-word` .

I hope I'm doing something wrong, because getting the client to fix or change *anything* on these ancient Linux installs will be extremely difficult. Can you spot what I've got wrong? Is there more info I need to provide?